# Do combat computers affect strike craft?

Tags: stellaris

Here's a combat computer:

[image: AI Combat Computer]

This computer adds some bonuses to fire rate, tracking, and chance to hit on weapons for a defense platform. If I equip my defense platform with strike craft, which as far as I can tell are separate ships generated by the hanger, does the combat computer confer it's bonuses to the strike craft?

Comment: Not sure if this is a valid answer but it seems to be the case. I'm saying this based on my strike craft-centric builds which improved after improving the combat AI.

Comment: Without actual testing, it is hard to know for sure; however, since strike craft are (at least in current builds) treated as a type of weapon - a sort of reusable missile - it is highly likely that the answer to your question is "Yes."